# Datagridgridview drag drop event

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a drag and drop function, and I am having just a little difficulty.

My questions are as follows:

1.) In reguards to the attached code, should Load_Load event be called first or does it matter what sequence it is in (as you can see, its the last event called in this group of code).

2.) The drag/drop event works, however when I click on a cell or column header, on grid two I get: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. How do I fix this item?

3.) In datagrid 2 cells 0 and 1 are numbered cell 0 and cell 1. when I hover over the two cells I get 0-1 for cell 0 and 1-2 for cell 1-the rest of the cellheaders are not numbered or have tool tips. How is this fixed?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Suite_Estimation
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
         {
            Point clientPoint = dataGridView1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));               
            dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.HitTest(clientPoint.X,      clientPoint.Y).RowIndex].Cells[dataGridView1.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y).ColumnIndex].Value = (System.String)e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.String));

         }
}

    private void dataGridView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
     if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    private void dataGridView2_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
     dataGridView2.DoDragDrop(dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString(), DragDropEffects.Copy);

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();

        dataGridView2.Rows.Add(5);
        dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "00000000";
        dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value = "11111111";
        dataGridView2.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value = "22222222";
        dataGridView2.Rows[3].Cells[0].Value = "33333333";
        dataGridView2.Rows[4].Cells[0].Value = "44444444";
        dataGridView2.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value = "0 - 1";
        dataGridView2.Rows[1].HeaderCell.Value = "1 - 2";
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1)
                dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(
                   dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                                .Cells[e.ColumnIndex]
                                .Value.ToString(), 
                   DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }

private void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
    {
        Point clientPoint = dataGridView1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        int rowIndex = dataGridView1.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y).RowIndex;
        int colIndex = dataGridView1.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y).ColumnIndex;
        if (rowIndex > -1 && colIndex > -1)
            dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Value =  
                           (System.String)e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.String));
    }
}
```

Comment: The cell and column header don't give exception using that code but the cell now gives System.NullReferenceException when I click on cell to drag it.

Comment: Actuall that worked-I changed your code to datagrid2 and it works, but I get an error if I don't drop exactly in the cell (like if I try to drop on a header or space where the rows are not added yet is gives exception: ArgumentOutOfRangeException. But that was very helpful thank you for that!